# Adjacency matrix must be symmetric

Tags: matlab, graph

**Problem**

I want to create an undirected graph from my EdgeList. But as my Edgelist is not a dense double array. I depleted all edge-connections containing zeros but I guess the problem is that the edgelist is not constant, this is the start of my edgelist:

```
Edgelist= 
    10965   10879
    10965   10962
    10965   10966
    10965   10967
    11382   11360
    11382   11381
    11382   11384
    11382   11553
    11383   11380
    11383   11381
    11383   11384
    11383   11389
```

So I try to create an adjacency matrix, in the hope of trying to prevent the `source is not a dense double array` error

**Code I use**

```
    EdgeList=unique(EdgeList,'rows');
    sz = max(EdgeList(:));
    A = sparse(EdgeList(:,1), EdgeList(:,2), 1, sz, sz);
    G=graph(A);
```

Now I get the next error

> Adjacency matrix must be symmetric.

I am running out of ideas how to create a graph from such a data set, can anyone help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must create your adjacency matrix to be symmetric as it says, because if `2` is adjacent to `3`: `A(2,3) == 1`, then `3` must also be adjacent to `2`: `A(3,2) == 1`. You have contructed your adjacency matrix in such a way that you only have a one-direction relationship for each edge.

You can correct this by either appending the other column of `EdgeList` to each of the inputs to `sparse`:

```
A = sparse([EdgeList(:,1); EdgeList(:,2)], [EdgeList(:,2); EdgeList(:,1)], 1);
```

Alternately, you can transpose your `A` and combine it with the initial version of `A` using a logical or (`|`) to force it to be symmetric.

```
A = A.' | A;
```